# Misplaced \omit for multicolumn in "if then else"-statement in tabular

Tags: pdftex, conditionals, multicolumn, booktabs

Since my update to the latest LaTex Distribution I am running into an `Misplaced \omit. }`-Error.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half+,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newcommand{\abrSummeA}{10.00}
\newcommand{\abrSummeB}{11.90}
\newcommand{\gift}{10.00}
\newcommand{\Steuer}{1}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lrrrr}

            Lorem   &Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \\\midrule %
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Gift}} &\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gift}}{\textbf{---}}{\gift} \EUR{
            } \\ \bottomrule[1pt]\addlinespace
            %
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\Steuer}}{%
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox{5cm}{\textbf{Sum A:}}}%
                & \num{\abrSummeB} \EUR{}%
            }{%
                \multicolumn{1}{l}{\parbox{5cm}{\textbf{SumA + SumB:}}}%
                    & \num{\abrSummeA}\EUR{}%
                    & \num{\abrSummeB}\EUR{}%
            }%                                                  <- LINE WITH ERROR !
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

The problem appears at l 38 and to make it short. I have no clue. The process finishes the processing (I get a pdf). But I would still like to resolve the error.

Any help idea? Thank you very much for your replies.
Best

Comment: `\ifthenelse` is not expandable, but if you need things like `\multicolumn` you need to be fully expandable until the `\omit` is read by TeX.

Comment: As an aside: If you specify the unit (in this case `\EUR{}`) in the head row it is wrong to put the unit in behind the values of each row of those columns.

Comment: @Skillmon . Yes you are right. I did not place the Euro sign in every cell after defining it in the table head. It is only mentioned in the multi-column sum which is breaking the column  layout and seperated by a `\bottomline`. So I placed the unit there again. For the minimal working example it is not done "good".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same remedy as in [Skillmon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647530/73317), simply a shorter way to “implement” an expandable `\ifundefined`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \ifundefined \cs_if_free:NTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half+,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newcommand{\abrSummeA}{10.00}
\newcommand{\abrSummeB}{11.90}
\newcommand{\gift}{10.00}
\newcommand{\Steuer}{1}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \ifundefined \cs_if_free:NTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
    Lorem   &Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \\\midrule %
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Gift}} &\ifundefined{\gift}{\textbf{---}}{\gift} \EUR{
    } \\ \bottomrule[1pt]\addlinespace
    %
    \ifundefined{\Steuer}{%
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox{5cm}{\textbf{Sum A:}}}%
                                      & \num{\abrSummeB} \EUR{}%
                                    }{%
                                      \multicolumn{1}{l}{\parbox{5cm}{\textbf{SumA + SumB:}}}%
                    & \num{\abrSummeA}\EUR{}%
                    & \num{\abrSummeB}\EUR{}%
                  }%                                                  <- LINE WITH ERROR !
                \end{tabular}
              \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You got the green tick, for the sake of the shorter solution :)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that some special tokens in alignments (so in `tabular` and similar environments) must be the first unexpandable token in a cell (`\multicolumn` expands to `\multispan` that expands to `\omit`). You can't have unexpandable material in front of those primitives (another one is `\noalign` which must be the first in a row, which is why you can't use `\hline` everywhere).

The following defines a test for an undefined macro that is fully expandable.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half+,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newcommand{\abrSummeA}{10.00}
\newcommand{\abrSummeB}{11.90}
\newcommand{\gift}{10.00}
\newcommand{\Steuer}{1}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\providecommand\@thirdofthree[3]{#3}
\newcommand\ifundefined[1]
  {%
    \ifdefined#1%
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    \@secondofthree
      {%
        \ifx\relax#1%
          \expandafter\@secondofthree
        \fi
        \@secondoftwo
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
    Lorem   &Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \EUR{} & Lorem \\\midrule %
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Gift}} &\ifundefined\gift{\textbf{---}}{\gift} \EUR{
    } \\ \bottomrule[1pt]\addlinespace
    %
    \ifundefined\Steuer{%
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox{5cm}{\textbf{Sum A:}}}%
                                      & \num{\abrSummeB} \EUR{}%
                                    }{%
                                      \multicolumn{1}{l}{\parbox{5cm}{\textbf{SumA + SumB:}}}%
                    & \num{\abrSummeA}\EUR{}%
                    & \num{\abrSummeB}\EUR{}%
                  }%                                                  <- LINE WITH ERROR !
                \end{tabular}
              \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't like `\@ifundefined` (or `\ltx@ifundefined`), do you? :-)

Comment: @frougon I don't have problems with `\@ifundefined`, it just doesn't have the used semantic of the question (namely it isn't used as `\@ifundefined\foo` but as `\@ifundefined{foo}`, and stripping the escape char from a `\string` seems unnecessarily complicated to get the syntax with the macro name).

Comment: I agree stripping would be way too complicated here, however `\NewCommandCopy{\ifUndefined}{\@ifundefined}` followed by `\ifUndefined{gift}` and `\ifUndefined{Steuer}` in the document body should be acceptable (I put a capital “U” because of the syntax inconsistency as compared to `\ifdefined`...). That said, practicing sport is sane, no worries! :-) (you got my +1 for correctness and good sport, precisely)

Comment: Before I leave you in peace: AFAIK, “first unexpandable token in a cell” should be “first non-space unexpandable token in a cell” (TeXbook p. 240).

Comment: @frougon quoting from the TeXbook: "If the very first token of an alignment entry is \``\omit`' (after macro expansion), then the template of the preamble is omitted;  ..." It just so happens that leading spaces don't start the entry :) (so are we both right?)

Comment: Tsssk tsssk... “Leading spaces” is too easy. You can have `\foo\bar\baz\space\quux\omit` at the beginning of an entry; if, e.g., `\foo\bar\baz` has null expansion and `\quux` expands to `\space`, the `\omit` will work “properly”. This exception for space tokens is useful to terminate ⟨number⟩s (not with `\relax`!) in expandable tests like `\ifnum` or `\ifcase` at the beginning of an entry, without closing the door for `\noalign` or `\omit` (I fixed a bug in some famous package thanks to this rule :-).

Comment: BTW, `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new_eq:NN \ifundefined \cs_if_free:NTF \ExplSyntaxOff` offers the desired syntax and semantics. :)

Comment: @frougon don't worry, I'm aware that the leading spaces are also stripped after each step of expansion testing for `\omit`, and yes, `\cs_if_free:NTF` does the same (just in a different order).

Comment: And you got not the green tick, but my upvote for the better explenation :D.
Thanks a lot! I am not so deep into Tex, but I think I understood, what you tried me to explain.

Comment: @benni don't challenge me for "shorter solution"...